# Changing observed property value in EventHandler changes Event properties

Tags: kotlin, javafx

I have a `TableView` with a column of `ComboBox` cells, created with `ComboBoxTableCell.forTableColumn()`.  I'm very new to JavaFX. You may want to skip to "TLDR" at the bottom before going through all of it.

In `onEditCommit()` for the column, I launch an `Alert` to get confirmation ("Really ____?").  If it isn't confirmed, I want the cell's value to revert to what it was originally. The observed property is a `SimpleStringProperty`, and the table/row/bean type is a `FooBar` object. The table is backed by an `ObservableList<FooBar>`, retrieved using the Event object. This is the `EventHandler`, in kotlin:

```
EventHandler { ev ->
    ev.newValue?.let { str ->

        println("A old ${ev.oldValue} ===> new ${ev.newValue}")

        list[ev.tablePosition.row]?.let { foobar ->
            if (str != foobar.prop.value) {
                val confirm = runDialog()
                if (!confirm) foobar.prop.value = ev.oldValue

                println("B old ${ev.oldValue} ---> new ${ev.newValue} "
                    +"| prop ${foobar.prop.value}")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The ComboBox has three options, "Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie".  Here's what happens when I select the ComboBox and change the value, but then cancel in the confirm dialoge (the actual output is indented):

```
[ Box reads "Alpha"; select "Beta" ]
    A old Alpha ===> new Beta
[ Cancel dialog... Box reads "Beta"
    B old Alpha ---> new Beta | prop Alpha
[ Repeat by selecting "Charlie" ]
    A old Alpha ===> new Charlie
[ Cancel dialog ]   
    B old Alpha ---> new Charlie | prop Alpha
[ Box reads "Charlie" ]
```

Notice that the property is being reset, but the cell contents aren't reflecting that.  I thought this might be an issue with what happens when the handler returns -- ie., the commit happens afterward -- but using `Platform.runLater()` to set the property did not make a difference.

What did is intuiting that the edit is never committed, ie., `foobar.prop.value` is always the same, so setting it to `oldValue` doesn't change anything.  However, the ComboBox is still out-of-sync with the property it is supposed to be an observer of.

This theory is supported by the fix, which is to stash `oldValue` and set `foobar.prop` to something new before running the dialog.

```
    val orig = ev.oldValue
    list[ev.tablePosition.row]?.let { foobar ->
        if (str != foobar.format.value) {
            // Set before dialog.
            foobar.format.value = ev.newValue
            val confirm = runDialog()
            if (!confirm()) foobar.format.value = orig
```

But what's a bit mysterious here is why `orig` is necessary at all -- why not just `foobar.format.value = ev.oldValue`?  Because `ev.oldValue` changes *in between* the third
last and last lines above; I'm guessing the `Event` object is actually being recycled and set with `foobar.format.value`.  Or it could have to do with the dialog, which probably makes it a bone fide bug.  Here's what happens using the fix:

```
[ Box reads "Alpha"; select "Beta" ]
    A old Alpha ===> new Beta
[ Cancel dialog... Box reads "Alpha"
    B old Alpha ---> new Beta | prop Alpha ]
```

So I am at least able to get what I want, but I am troubled by all this unexpected behaviour.
Here's what happens if, instead of using `orig`, I change that assignment to `ev.oldValue` (with no other changes):

```
[ Box reads "Alpha"; select "Beta" ]
    A old Alpha ===> new Beta
[ Cancel dialog... Box reads "Beta" ]
    B old Beta ---> new Beta | prop Beta
```

Back to the same problem.

### (TLDR) This means changing `foobar.prop.value` in the handler has the side affect of changing `ev.oldValue`.

Confirmed with:

```
println("old ${ev.oldValue}")
foobar.prop.value = ev.newValue
println("old now ${ev.oldValue}")
```

Which I guess is the short version of this question. I'm sure I'm not the first to notice this. Is that behaviour expected, documented or easily explicable? I suppose there is a certain desirability in it, but it makes the `Event` object seem a bit shifty.

**There's also the matter of the ComboBox falling out of sync with the value, which does not seem desirable at all.**

This is openjfx 11 on x64 linux.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: @kleopatra I don't see the point *if* this is actually expected and explicable on the basis of what's here already.  You asking for one of course implies it *isn't*, in which case the SCCCE  is needed to isolate my mistake.  If anyone can say definitively that what's in that last three three line snippet should NOT happen (ie., that `oldValue` should be the same before and after  setting `prop.value`, where `prop` is the property source of `oldValue`) then I do need to take some time and dive deeper.  But I suspect this is not the case...

Comment: ..and that the reason is either 1) The `Event` object is recycle optimized or explicitly 1:1 related under the hood and is affected by setting the property with which it is associated, or 2) `oldValue` refers to/is a getter for the same object in both the property and the event, hence changing one changes the other.

Comment: _that oldValue should be the same before and after setting prop.value_ exactly that's what I expect .. and why I need a [mcve] to see what's going wrong (preferably in plain fx, my taste for sugar is .. underdeveloped ;)